# Website Backlinks are not showing in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, wordpress, backlinks

I have put my website links in social media sites, forums and article sites. But these links are not showing in google search console or any other backlink checker sites.

Comment: This takes a long time and you may never see all of them. It can take months! It is not something to worry about. For the record, the only site that counts is Google and Bing. The other websites are mostly junk. Cheers!!

Comment: `I have put my website links in social media, forums and article sites`, Google penalises for self-created links, unless they are from content relevant sites they will likely hurt your rankings and not help. Google's algorithm looks for diversity, if your links are on a number of platforms that Google understands as 'SELF-Creating' and low quality, it will hurt you...some eg: Bursts of social media posts on reddit, digg etc, also low quality forum signature or profile links, and non-relevant forums. or article submission sites such as ezinearticles, etc. Links can be more harmful than good.

Comment: Furthermore, this question has been asked already in various forms on Pro Webmasters. But to answer your question... Google may never show them, it doesn't reveal all links, only sample of them... additionally it can take months to display them.